# Kotlin when keyboard show scroll inputs but hide bottom bar

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll, keyboard, scrollview

I have a layout like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="com.example.uniuniverse.R" />

        <variable
            name="fragment"
            type="com.example.uniuniverse.presentation.profile.addUser.AddUserFragment" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomBarGeneral"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout7">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardView4"
                    android:layout_width="175dp"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="#52335B"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="100dp"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout13"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/addUserPhoto"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:maxHeight="175dp"
                        android:minWidth="175dp"
                        android:minHeight="175dp"
                        android:scaleType="center"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_add_user" />

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout13"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="15dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="15dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="15dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="15dp"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
                    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
                    app:counterTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/icon_username"
                    app:endIconMode="custom"
                    app:endIconScaleType="center"
                    app:endIconTint="@color/white"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout14"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView4"
                    app:placeholderTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:prefixTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:suffixTextColor="@color/white">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/addUserName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/style_profile_inputs"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/karla_variable_font_wght"
                        android:hint="Kullanıcı Adı"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout14"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="15dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="15dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="15dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="15dp"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
                    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
                    app:counterTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/icon_departmant"
                    app:endIconMode="custom"
                    app:endIconScaleType="center"
                    app:endIconTint="@color/white"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout15"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout13"
                    app:placeholderTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:prefixTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:suffixTextColor="@color/white">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/addUserDepartmant"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/style_profile_inputs"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/karla_variable_font_wght"
                        android:hint="Bölüm"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout15"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="15dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="15dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="15dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="15dp"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
                    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
                    app:counterTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/icon_gradle"
                    app:endIconMode="custom"
                    app:endIconScaleType="center"
                    app:endIconTint="@color/white"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout16"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout14"
                    app:placeholderTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:prefixTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:suffixTextColor="@color/white">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/addUserClass"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/style_profile_inputs"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/karla_variable_font_wght"
                        android:hint="Sınıf"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout16"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="15dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="15dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="15dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="15dp"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
                    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
                    app:counterTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/icon_universty"
                    app:endIconMode="custom"
                    app:endIconScaleType="center"
                    app:endIconTint="@color/white"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout15"
                    app:placeholderTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:prefixTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:suffixTextColor="@color/white">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/addUserUni"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/style_profile_inputs"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/karla_variable_font_wght"
                        android:hint="Üniversite"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_primary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/karla_variable_font_wght"
                    android:text="UniUniverse - Kullanıcı Ekle"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btnBackSyllabus"
                    navigate="@{R.id.addToMain}"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_back"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView12" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btnInfoSyllabus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_info"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView12" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </FrameLayout>


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomBarGeneral"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_primary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addUser"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/karla_variable_font_wght"
                android:onClick="@{()->fragment.onCreateUser()}"
                android:text="Kaydet"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:cornerRadius="20dp"
                app:icon="@drawable/icon_save"
                app:iconGravity="end"
                app:iconPadding="8dp"
                app:iconSize="12dp"
                app:iconTint="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:strokeColor="@color/white"
                app:strokeWidth="1.5dp" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

[Layout view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWNnE.png)
I want to do when user click the textInputLayout, do scrollView can be scroll but dont show the bottom of button

I try Manifest android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan,resize,nothing..........everything", i think i have a problem in layout.

[After the android:fitsSystemWindows="true"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0gBN.png)
when i do android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in scrollView, gaps remain as in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:windowSoftInputMode` and remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

Your layout will be look like below-

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBarGeneral">

        <!-- your content -->

    </ScrollView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBarGeneral"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <!-- your content-->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

These changes will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks it's worked but my style like this;
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
This blocked to worked what can i do?